# Strange error for passing a character value within a character function

Tags: c++

I am attempting to check if an input character is a character. I then have a function that makes it an upper case character if it is lower case. For some reason though, upon compilation, when I call my upper case function in my main function, I'm getting a strange error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'char' to 'std::ios_base &'. What exactly is 'ios_base &' (I assume the ios_base &) is some kind of referenced address. Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char userChar;
    cout << "Please enter a char to be converted to capital: " << endl;
    cin >> userChar;

    if ((userChar >= 'a' ) && (userChar <= 'z')) {
        char upperCaseChar = uppercase(userChar);
        cout << "Character capitalized is " << upperCaseChar << endl;
    }
    else if (isupper(userChar)) {
        cout << "Character is already capitalized and is " << userChar << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

char uppercase(char ch) { 
        return ch - 'a' + 'A'; 

}
```

It's a simple program, I'm writing it because I will have to translate it to assembly. Thanks!

Comment: You have `using namespace std` which means you have a conflict with [`std::uppercase`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/uppercase/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a function before calling it. Either add this line before `main`:

```
char uppercase(char ch);
```

or move the entire `uppercase` function to be before `main`.

This is a good illustration of why it is not recommend to do `using namespace std`. There are a lot of things in `std`,  including `std::uppercase`.  The error message comes because at the point of your call `uppercase(userChar);`, the only visible definition of `uppercase` was `std::uppercase` which expects a `std::ios_base` argument.

You call another undeclared function later, `isupper`. If you meant `std::isupper` then you need `#include <cctype>`.

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful (I'm a Java programmer transitioning into a C++ programmer for my Computer Organization class).

Answer (score 1):

- Don't create your own bicycles.
- Use `int toupper(int c)` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/
- Or this `template <class charT>
  charT std::toupper (charT c, const locale& loc);` - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/toupper/
- And it looks like you have no prototype of your `uppercase` before `main()`.